# How many stages are there in Danmaku Unlimited 2?

Tags: danmaku-unlimited-2

While playing Boss Rush mode, I realized it stopped at the 5th boss. Are there really only five stages, or did Boss Rush only go that far because that is as far as I went in the normal game type?

Comment: I would go test it out my self, but I am asking this from a computer that it is not installed on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official web site](http://doragongames.com/danmaku2/):

> Battle countless enemies as you fight across 5 beautiful, action-packed stages